# what is the spelling rule that applies to "zeros" and "heroes"?

Tags: grammaticality

What is the proper spelling rule that applies to "zeros", "heroes" and the like?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, there is no proper rule.

As [this site says](http://www.grammar-monster.com/plurals/plural_of_hero.htm):

> There is confusion because the rule for forming plurals with nouns ending in o isn't straightforward.
>
> Most nouns will just add an s. For example:
> *Piano becomes pianos*
> Some add es. For example:
> *Echo becomes echoes*
> With some words, both versions are accepted. For example:
> *Volcano becomes volcanoes or volcanos*

So when in doubt, look it up. There are probably individual (etymological) reasons to explain why *some* words take *-es*, but there doesn't seem to be an actual one-rule-to-rule-them-all rule.